# Обучение рекуррентных нейронных сетей keras

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Всем добрый день.

Я занимаюсь машинным обучением и недавно перешёл на RNN. Я пытаюсь решить задачу генерации музыки, но не в виде миди файла, а как набор PMC данных. Насколько я понимаю из всех прочитанных мною статей, именно рекуррентные сети могут справиться с этой задачей. Вопрос в том, что я не понимаю, каким образом необходимо задать input_shape модели, чтобы она обучалась. На входе имею одномерный массив преобразованных данных аудио файла с заданным samplerate. Хотелось бы получить на выходе сетку, которая при подаче на вход случайного сигнала продолжала бы генерировать звук.

Просидев с этой проблемой примерно неделю, так и не разобрался, как заставить полученную модель разворачиваться на всю длину входных данных и продолжать генерировать последовательность нужной длины. Каждый раз модели, которые я получал, обучались только на выделенном числе последних точек в последовательности данных, а не воспринимали весь аудиофайл целиком, в чем основное преимущество RNN, насколько я понял.

Используется Python3, tensorflow, keras.

Comment: Также был бы очень благодарен человеку, который помог бы перевести этот вопрос на английский, дабы задать его на англоязычной версии stackoverflow

Comment: Без кода и примера входных и выходных данных на данный вопрос вам врядли ответят и на англоязычной версии SO...

Comment: @MaxU, Я не могу привести пример кода, по той причине, что это и есть суть вопроса. Могу привести только пример входных данных, хотя мне казалось, что я достаточно подробно их описал, и того, что я бы хотел получить. Могу также привести пример несостоявшейся модели, но не думаю, что это поможет в ответе на мой вопрос.

Comment: Я как раз о "несостоявшейся" модели - по правилам форума надо привести пример кода, который не получается или с которым возникли проблемы. Если код рабочий, то и вопрос задавать смысла нет... ;)